# Failed to call export default on dependency injection

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Good night everyone, well what I'm trying to do is to inject the axios by bind in the loadUA function, but when importing as default in the component I get this error. The reason is I want to eliminate the axion dependency in the method so that I can perform the test more easily, without the bind in load everything works, but I can not inject axes by bind and use the method in the component.

> **Componet**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import loadUA from './actions'

class UserAgent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.loadUA()
    }
    render(){
        if(this.props.isFetching){
            return <span> Loading ...</span>
        }
        if(this.props.error){
            return <span>Error</span>
        }
        return (
            <span>{this.props.data['user-agent']}</span>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isFetching: state.UA.isFetching,
        data: state.UA.data,
        error: state.UA.error
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return {
        loadUA: () => dispatch(loadUA())
    }
}
export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )(UserAgent)
```

> **action**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const loadUARequest = () => {
    return {
        type: 'LOAD_UA_REQUEST'
    }
}
export const loadUASuccess = (data) => {
    return{
        type: 'LOAD_UA_SUCCESS',
        data
    }
}
export const loadUAError =() =>{
    return{
        type: 'LOAD_UA_ERROR'
    }
}
export const loadUA = (axios) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(loadUARequest())
        axios
            .get('https://httpbin.org/user-agent')
            .then(({data}) => dispatch(loadUASuccess(data)))
            .catch(() => dispatch(loadUAError()))
    }
}
export default {
    loadUA: loadUA.bind(null, axios)
}
```

> **Error**

[image]

Comment: you are default exporting an object not function so you need to access it as: `loadUA.loadUA()` here: `dispatch(loadUA.loadUA())`, otherwise you are already exporting it as named export so import it as `import { loadUA } from './actions'`

Comment: Thank you for your attention. That way the problem persists, if I import as non-default the function comes without the bind, but I just solved the problem, just export as standard the method and the bind. Solved. `export default loadUA.bind(null, axios)` and `import loadUA from './actions'`. The rest remained as it was. Thank you.